# Beamer: change font in math mode for one slide

Tags: beamer, fonts

I want to set the font of equations to computer modern (as in articles) only for specific slides. This is, change the font in the middle of the presentation.

`\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` works but changes the formulas in all the document.

I tried, without success: `\setbeamerfont{math tex}{\family=\rmfamily}`, `\renewcommand\mathfamilydefault{\rmdefault}`

I also tried, to check, `\setbeamertemplate{math text}{\small}`. But it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `sansmath` package to switch between sans serif and serif math:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \[
  abc
  \]
\end{frame}

\begingroup
  \unsansmath
  \begin{frame}
    \[
    abc
    \]
  \end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
  \[
  abc
  \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```